# Копировать атрибуты из domain model в view model/ получить значение атрибута

Tags: c#, asp, атрибуты

```
public class A_domain
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class A_view
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Как можно скопировать атрибут "StringLength" в A_view? Так что бы всегда быть уверенным что данные не отличаются. На данный момент я делал так:

```
public class A_domain
{
        public const int MaxTitleLength = 50;
        [StringLength(MaxTitleLength)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        ...
  }

public class A_view
{
     [StringLength(A_domain.MaxTitleLength)]
      public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Работает конечно, но мне кажется что есть какое то более верное/красивое решение.(потому что когда таких полей больше одного это принуждает писать много лишнего когда, который отвлекает от сути ).

И как потом получить это значение?

```
void foo()
{
   A_view a = new A_view();
   a.Title //get max length 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, это не правильно. Если между вашими классами имеется связь, то эту связь надо обозначить программно, т.е. через родственный класс или интерфейс. Например:

```
public class Element
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

И наследовать этот класс:

```
public class A_view:Element
{}
public class A_domain:Element
{}
```

Если же необходимо получить число 50 из атрибута почитайте статью про извлечение информации из атрибутов [от Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/attributes/retrieving-information-stored-in-attributes)